# after uninstalling visual studio 2013 error getting opening SQL Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2012, after un-installing visual studio 2013 I am getting an error on opening SQL Server 2012. The error I am getting when I am doing a run -> 
SSMS is

```
Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.
```

Can somebody please help me why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling Visual Studio might have affected some shared components needed by SQL Server Management Studio. Running a repair of your SQL Server installation should fix the problem.